# How to calculate nth character of fibonacci word?

Tags: c, fibonacci

The problem is to find nth character of first line (in Fibonacci word sequence) whose length is larger than given length.

Example:

```
A = 1415926535  
B = 8979323846  
Find F(n) for n = 35  
The first few terms of  are:  
1415926535,  
8979323846,  
1415926535 8979323846,  
8979323846 1415926535 8979323846,  
1415926535 8979323846 8979323846 1415926535 8979323846
```

Here fifth line is first to contain more than 35 characters so F(35) = 35th character that is 9 is the answer.

I tried using array of structure defined as

```
typedef struct obj
{
    struct obj *one;
    struct obj *two;
    char len[101]; //Given maximum length 100
    char string;
} OBJ;
OBJ result[300]; //Given that n < 2^100 which means around 250 lines max. 

//Here i denotes line number.
result[1].string = 'a';
strcpy(result[1].len, len_a);
result[2].string = 'b';
strcpy(result[2].len, len_b);
int i = 3;
while (1)
{
    result[i].one = &result[i - 2];
    result[i].two = &result[i - 1];
    strcpy(result[i].len, addStrings(result[i - 1].len, result[i-2].len));
    if (compareStrings(result[i].len, char_n) >= 0)
        break;
    i++;
}  
while (1)
{
    if (solution->string == 'a')
    {
        n = strtoull(char_n, &end, 10);
        return a[n - 1];
    }
    if (solution->string == 'b')
    {
        n = strtoull(char_n, &end, 10);
        return b[n - 1];
    }
    if (compareStrings(solution->one->len, char_n) >= 0)
    { 
        solution = solution->one;
        i -= 2;
    }
    else
    {
        char_n = subStrings(char_n, solution->one->len); 
        //n = n-len(one)
        solution = solution->two;
        i -= 1;
    }
}
```

where pointer one held pointer to second last element, pointer two held pointer to last element, len held length of string. Here len is string to handle numbers greater than 2^64. Functions to add and subtract are defined and working in all cases I tried. Full code here: [Second attempt][4]

Failing around 9 tests. Am I still missing something?

Comment: Are you asking for a solution to a [project Euler coding challenge](https://projecteuler.net/problem=230)? Isn't the real challenge to do what you are asking, yourself?

Comment: Yes. I already did it but in python. I want to know how it can be done in C.

Comment: You've lost me.  You talk about position 127,654,101,697,653,297, and positions such as 2^50 but you're passing around `int` variables whose limit is 2^31 (i.e. 2,147,483,648).  It shouldn't just be slow at these extremes, it should be incorrect.  The top rated answer in the SO question you cited, and said you followed, is all about dealing with large indicies but I don't see *any* of that in your **C**, nor Python, code.  What am I missing?

Comment: Your question was originally about your code *speed*, now it has been rewrittent to be about your *broken* algorithm.  I have deleted my answer accordingly.